# Open application without tapping on icon

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

Is there any way by which we can launch the app by the external volume button or by any other gestures made on the iPhone instead of launching by the default way?

OR

Can our app recognise the users interaction with the volume button when app is in the background?

Answer (score 3):

> Open application without tapping on icon

you can open app by firing the local or push notification, and it will allow you to get inside your app when allowed. That is the answer of you Heading hope it helps you. Check apple [documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/#next). For your detailed question the answers are given above. I know the answer is irrelevant but hope it help for you if you are trying for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way by which we can launch the app by the external volume button or by any other gestures made on the iPhone instead of launching by the default way? :

No It's not possible. It's now allowed. There's no way you can achieve this. Apple don't allow this under **User Experience** section. You can't force open you app unless user don't tap on icon.

> Can our app recognise the users interaction with the volume button when app is in the background? :

Yes it does recognize the volume change. However, you can't notify your app that user is doing some action. And perform any action depending on volume change.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the first part of the question but does not address the second part which is possible (depending on what you want to do).

Comment: @CraftyThumber : I think Prashant is trying to open the app on volume button. I edited my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way by which we can launch the app by the external volume button or by any other gestures made on the iPhone instead of launching by the default way?

I'm pretty sure this is not possible.

> Can our app recognise the users interaction with the volume button when app is in the background?

Well there are other apps which recognise this such as Spotify and Sonos so this is possible.

**Playing Background Audio**

An app that plays audio continuously (even while the app is running in the background) can register as a background audio app by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the value audio) in its Info.plist file. Apps that include this key must play audible content to the user while in the background.

[Apple reference "Playing Background Audio"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

[Ensuring That Audio Continues When the Screen Locks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW32)

For enabling/disabling this feature I found [Activating and Deactivating Your Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW23), I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like what you need.

I don't know if this is possible for other operations other than background audio...

Comment: thanx Crafty but i was trying. I am not able to find out,so please say how can it be achieved, please give some suggestions.

Comment: @PrashantChaudhari: Please be clear about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to run arbitrary routines on user interaction with the volume buttons because I don't think that is possible. If you want to register your app as an audio session so it can respond to the volume keys when in the background (in the expected way) then try reading the links in the answer.